# Proof for: If $x>-a$ for $a>0$, then $x\geq0$

Tags: inequality

I came across a claim that

If
$$
x>-a \text{ }\forall \text{ } a>0
$$
then
$$
x\geq0
$$
This claim is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670132/bounded-function-has-limit-between-bounds) (the answer).

When graphed, $x$ does occupy places between $-a$ and $0$ and therefore I don't understand how $x\geq0$ except when $a$ is close enough to zero such that the only 'next' number on the number line is zero so that $x\geq0$. How could I formally prove this is true (if it is true) or otherwise?

Comment: $$x>-a\qquad\forall a>0$$ means that $x$ is strictly greater than any strictly negative number (alternatively, $x\ge\sup\{-a:a\in\mathbb R, a>0\}=0$.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of $\forall\epsilon>0:a<b+\epsilon\implies a\le b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724832/proof-of-forall-epsilon0ab-epsilon-implies-a-le-b)

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it does! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\;x\;$ were negative, by letting $\;a=-x>0\;,\;$ we would get that $\;x>-a=x\;,\;$ but it is a contradiction, so $\;x\;$ cannot be negative, hence $\;x\geqslant0\;.$

Answer (score 0):

By contradiction if $x \lt 0$, then

$$0 \gt - (-x /2) \gt x$$ with $-(x/2) \gt 0$. A contradiction with the hypothesis $x \gt -a$ for all $a \gt 0$.